# Rotation of a 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

The first line will contain numbers `m` (number of rows), `n` (number of columns), and `b` (number of rotations to be performed).

Suppose I have following 4X4 matrix:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> 9 10 11 12
> 13 14 15 16
> ```

and b = 1,the output must be:

> ```
> 2 3 4 8
> 1 7 11 12
> 5 6 10 16
> 9 13 14 15
> ```

The problem I am facing is 3 test case are timing out and 9 test case successfully passed. Can somebody suggest a way or help me with optimizing my code?

[Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo) is the link to the question.

I need a way to figure out how to minimize `b`, because some rotations will be useless as it will result in giving us the original array.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class So {
    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static int n,m,b;
    private static int [][]arr;    
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {        
        int i,j;
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String []str;
        str=br.readLine().split(" ");
        m=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        n=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        b=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
        arr=new int[m][n];
        for(i=0;i<m;++i)
        {
            str=br.readLine().split(" ");
            for(j=0;j<n;++j)
             arr[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(str[j]);
        }
        i=0;
        while(i++<b)        
         rotate();       
        for(i=0;i<m;++i)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;++j)
             System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");             
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void rotate()
    {
        int sr=0,sc=0,r=m,c=n,i,j,prev,res;
        while(sr<=r-2&&sc<=c-2)
        {prev=arr[sr][sc];        
        res=arr[sr+1][sc];
        for(i=sr+1;i<=r-2;++i)
        {
            arr[i][sc]=prev;
            prev=res;
            res=arr[i+1][sc];
        }
        for(i=sc;i<=c-2;++i)
        {
            arr[r-1][i]=prev;
            prev=res;
            res=arr[r-1][i+1];
        }
        for(i=r-1;i>=sr+1;--i)
        {
            arr[i][c-1]=prev;
            prev=res;
            res=arr[i-1][c-1];
        }
        for(i=c-1;i>=sc+1;--i)
        {
            arr[sr][i]=prev;
            prev=res;
            res=arr[sr][i-1];
        } 
        arr[sr][sc]=prev;
        sr++;sc++;r--;c--;
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any limit on the number of rotations?  Can it be in the millions?

Comment: @JS1 yes it can be.

Comment: @JS1 You have pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @JS1 Can you suggest me as to how to fiqure out exact number of rotations required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reduce the number of rotations

For each "ring" you rotate, the number of rotations you can do before you reach the original position again is: \$2*(rows + columns) - 4\$, where `rows` and `columns` are the number of rows and columns for the ring.  So you can reduce the number of rotations like this:

```
sizeOfRing = 2*(r-sr + c-sc) - 4;
rotationsForThisRing = totalRotations % sizeOfRing;
```

You will of course need to modify your program to use a variable number of rotations per ring.

Comment: Sorry,But now for the same test case,the output is coming wrong,instead of timeout. The test case are too long too be specified here or in question.

Comment: I think that we must not forget that m and n can have any combination of even and odd.

Comment: @Dante. Your code will look completely different if you did it correctly because your rotation function would need to have the total number of rotations passed in as an argument, and it should only be called once.  I suggest you simply test your program with various inputs and find out what is failing.

Comment: Its not failing,its timing out.

Comment: @Dante. You said "the output is coming wrong,instead of timeout".  Which is it?

Comment: If I include your ring code, then its failing and my code is timing out.I hope you get it now.

Comment: @Dante. You probably didn't do the ring code correctly.  You should print out the result using your old code vs your new code and see if you can spot any differences.

Comment: What exactly are you implying?

Comment: @Dante. "If I include your ring code, then its failing" means that there is a bug.  To debug, run the buggy version versus the correct version to find the difference.  I could easily just post a complete bug free solution but that wouldn't help you learn as much as if you wrote and debugged the solution yourself.

Comment: Finally did it.I also arrived at your solution.

Comment: So did not felt the need of posting another answer.